# How to get Sun X4100 Firmware updates from Oracle?

Tags: oracle, sun, firmware

This document directs how to get there, but it is for the old Sun website. http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19569-01/820-1188-12/core_ilom_firmware.html#50413605_67571

> Download the flash image .ima file using these steps:
>
> 1. Naviage to http://www.sun.com/download/
> 2. Locate the Hardware Drivers section.
> 3. Click the X64 Servers and Workstations.
> 4. Click the link for the Integrated Lights Out Manager (ILOM) Server
>      software release version that you want.
>
> ...

Under the new Oracle site, how do I get to the X4100 firmware updates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the Oracle firmware page: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/systems/patches/firmware/release-history-jsp-138416.html

Answer (score 1):

Oracle insists on a "support identifier" and matching company name before downloading anything from them.  There is no apparent way to get this, so it seems that they effectively block further support for old Sun hardware unless you're willing to pay to be an Oracle hardware reseller.  :-(

The easiest way to get past this problem is to ask around for someone that does have access to the Oracle's support site.  Technicians or Engineers working for corporations that have support contracts for Sun/Oracle servers should be able to help you (if they want to!)

From the [page](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/systems/patches/firmware/release-history-jsp-138416.html?ssSourceSiteId=ocomen)

> To find your download on My Oracle Support:
>
> 1. List item
> 2. Sign in to My Oracle Support.
> 3. Click the "Patches & Updates" tab.
> 4. In the "Patch Search" box on the left side, select "Product or Family (Advanced)" search.
> 5. Enter a partial product name for "Product is" - a list of matches will be displayed. Select the product of interest.
> 6. Select one or more "releases" in the "Release is" drop down and close the pop-up window.
> 7. At the bottom of that window click on the Search button and a list of product downloads (listed as patches) will be displayed. Select the
>      Patch Name of interest. This will take you to the Download Page.
>
> If, on the Download Information Page, you get the message "You do not
>   have permissions to download this Patch...", see How Patches and
>   Updates Entitlement Works to help you determine the reason.