# Looking for Firmware for Oracle Dual 40 Gb Ethernet Adapter

Tags: networking, oracle, drivers, firmware, adapter

I purchased an Oracle Dual 40 Gb Ethernet Adapter - [documentation here](https://www.oracle.com/a/ocom/docs/10gbor40gbethernetadapter-ds-2968185.pdf).

The card was sold to me as pure Intel. I realised it was OEM after I installed the card and checked it on Linux, but meanwhile the seller **disappeared** of course.

I politely ask to help me and give me a hint, where I could get

- the latest NVM firmware
- Oracle firmware update tool

for that network adapter,so I can update the card and let it work with my QSFP+ SR4 breakout cables (4x10 GbE) or SFP SX/LX optical modules (single speed) - current NVM v4.26 does not support these optics. Maybe someone on ServerFault would have access to MOS [here](https://www.oracle.com/servers/technologies/support-matrix.html). I could then update firmware over Oracle Linux. Would appreciate your help and pay with leg or something!

I have same problem as guys [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/292669/how-to-get-sun-x4100-firmware-updates-from-oracle?rq=1).

I have searched Oracle website, found documentation under the link provided in my first sentence above.
[Oracle firmware download site](https://www.oracle.com/downloads/opensource/networking-source-code-downloads.html) does not list ethernet adapters. I only was able to register on Oracle Support site and [download Port Configuration Software QCU](https://www.oracle.com/webapps/redirect/signon?nexturl=https://download.oracle.com/otn/other/QCU.tar), but [firmware patches and firmware update tool](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E52095_01/html/E52099/gomnz.html#scrolltoc) are provided only if you have maintenance support. Contacted Oracle Support - they require an enterprise account on support site :( Have placed my request on  [Oracle Forum1](https://forums.oracle.com/ords/apexds/post/oracle-server-x8-8-options-cards-0216) and [Oracle Forum2](https://www.orafaq.com/forum/m/689311/?srch=Oracle+Dual+40+Gb+Ethernet+Adapter#msg_689311) without any result.

Comment: Isn't the firmware automatically shipped as part of the OS? That it's automatically recognized. For Debian for example in the non-free firmware

Comment: Thank you for the hint! Will download Oracle Linux and check.

Comment: No try with debian, with a live cd for example.

Answer (score 0):

Try the non-free firmware of Debian for example

Set this in your /etc/apt/sources.list

```
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm main contrib non-free non-free-firmware
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm main contrib non-free non-free-firmware

deb http://deb.debian.org/debian-security bookworm-security main contrib non-free non-free-firmware
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian-security bookworm-security main contrib non-free non-free-firmware

deb http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm-updates main contrib non-free non-free-firmware
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm-updates main contrib non-free non-free-firmware
```

Comment: Dear @Turdie, thank you very much for the info. Question: I'm trying to update the NVM version on the card to enable support for QSFP+ SR4 breakout cables (4x10 GbE). Can I do that with Debian firmware? The card is running on latest Debian now and I can check the NVM version of the card, but the card does not support QSFP+ SR4 breakout cables (4x10 GbE) - I strongly assume due to the old NVM version (v4.26 according to ethtool -i output on Debian CLI). non-free non-free-firmware is already in the /etc/apt/sources.list

Answer (score 0):

Have found Oracle firmware for the card and was able to flash NVM.